# What is the purpose of the "gamma" parameter in SVMs?

Tags: machine-learning, support-vector-machine, hyper-parameters

I want to understand what the `gamma` parameter does in an SVM. According to [this page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_rbf_parameters.html).

> Intuitively, the `gamma` parameter defines how far the influence of a single training example reaches, with low values meaning ‘far’ and high values meaning ‘close’. The `gamma` parameters can be seen as the inverse of the radius of influence of samples selected by the model as support vectors.

I don't understand this part "**of a single training example reaches**", does it refer to the training dataset?

Answer (score 2):

I've summarized the [key ideas of SVMs](https://martin-thoma.com/svm-with-sklearn/). So this is how $\gamma$ is used with a gaussian Kernel:

$$K_{\text{Gauss}}(\mathbf{x}_i, \mathbf{x}_j) = e^{\frac{-\gamma\|\mathbf{x}_i - \mathbf{x}_j\|^2}{2 \sigma^2}}$$

The bigger the $\gamma$, the more "linear" the decision boundary will be. The closer to 0, the more support vectors you have/the more non-linear the boundary is (see [**interactive example**](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/karpathy/svmjs/demo/))

You can also find it on udacity: [SVM Gamma Parameter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m2a2K4lprQw)

In practice, you can use a [grid search](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV) or random search to get good values.

Comment: I think you meant:
the bigger the $\sigma$, or equivalently, the smaller the $\gamma$, the more "linear" the decision boundary will be

Answer (score 1):

Rougly speaking, the higher the gamma, the more complex the model, the higher the risk of overfitting.

In fact, as you can read on the page you linked:

> If **gamma is too large**, the radius of the area of influence of the
>   support vectors **only includes the support vector itself**[...]
>
> When **gamma is very small**, the model is too constrained and **cannot
>   capture the complexity or “shape” of the data**. The **region of influence
>   of any selected support vector would include the whole training set**.

Comment: i not understanding this "of a single training example reaches"

Comment: Replace "a single" with "each individual".